# Call Partial view another view with model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I call Partial View(with model) in another view(with model).
My Index View has model and my partial view has model.How to call my partial view in the Index view.

Error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HR_CLUB_AZ.Models.Posts]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HR_CLUB_AZ.Models.Test'.

My View:

```
@model List<HR_CLUB_AZ.Models.Posts>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Home/Shared/_LayoutHome.cshtml";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ana Səhifə</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Style/Home/img/logoIcon.ico">

    <meta name=" viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Style/Home/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Style/Home/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Style/Home/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <main class="site-main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="" style="width:85%;margin:0 auto;">
                    <div>
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero.jpg" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero1.png" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero2.jpg" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero3.png" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero4.jpg" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero5.jpg" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero6.png" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                        <img class="mySlides" src="~/Style/Home/img/hero7.png" style="width:100%" height="370" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="sliderBtnLeft" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                    <button class="sliderBtnRight" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="services">
            <h2 class="section-title">Xidmətlər</h2>
            <p class="desc"></p>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 serviceBackground">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="@Url.Action("StajCalc")">İR üzrə proqramlar</a></h4>
                                <p>
                                    İnsan resursları ilə bağlı müəyyən <br />əməliyyatların və
                                    hesablamaların, tərtib etdiyimiz proqramlar <br />vasitəsilə
                                    sadə üsulla həll edilməsi.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 serviceBackground">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                <i class="fa fa-balance-scale"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">İnsan Resurslarının idarə olunması</h4>
                                <p>
                                    zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad
                                    zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 serviceBackground">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">İR üzrə sənədlər</h4>
                                <p>
                                    Kadr kargüzarlığına aid ərizə və <br />əmr nümunələri və eyni
                                    zamanda insan resurslarına aid hər hansısa bir prosedur<br />
                                    barədə bizə müraciət edə bilərsiniz.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 serviceBackground">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">İR üzrə kitablar</h4>
                                <p>
                                    İnsan resurslarına aid kitabları <br />paylaşaraq bildiklərimizi
                                    sizinlə bölüşür, eynilə də siz kimlərinsə bilgilənməsi üçün<br />
                                    özünüzdə olan kitabları bizimlə bölüşə bilərsiniz.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 serviceBackground">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Konsultasiya</h4>
                                <p>
                                    zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad
                                    zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 serviceBackground">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                <i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">CV nümunələri</h4>
                                <p>
                                    zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad
                                    zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad zad
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div style="background-color:#6287ff;height: 360px;width: 100%">
            <br />
            <div style="float: left;color:#000;margin-left: 140px">
                <h3 style="text-align:left;color:#000000;margin-left:150px">Sorğu</h3>
                <br />
                <p style="font-weight:bold">Sizcə çalışanların ən çox hansı hüquqları pozulur ?</p>
                <p />
                <form action="">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender"> İşə qəbul<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender"> Məzuniyyət<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender"> Əmək haqqı<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender"> Bilmirəm<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender"> Fikrim yoxdur<p>
                        <br />
                        <button>Səs ver</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="test">
                @Html.Partial("PartialTest", model: Model)
            </div>


        </div>
        <section class="home-area">
            <div class="home_content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12"><h2 class="sub_title">SON XƏBƏRLƏR</h2></div>
                        <div class="home_list">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var md in Model)
                                {
                                    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="thumbnail">
                                            <img src="~/Style/Home/img/h1.jpeg" />
                                            <div class="caption">
                                                <h3><a href="#">@md.Title</a></h3>
                                                <p>@md.Description</p>
                                                <a href="@Url.Action("SinglePost", new { id = md.Id })" class="btn btn-link" role="button">Ətraflı</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div id="facebook" style="text-align:center">
            <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId" width="450" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

My Partial View:

```
@model HR_CLUB_AZ.Models.Test

@using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptTest", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div style="float: right;color:#000;margin-right: 140px" id="Test">
        <h3 style="text-align:right;color:#000000;margin-right:240px">Test</h3>
        <br />
        <p style="font-weight:bold">@Html.Label(Model.Question)</p>
        <p />
        <form action="">
            <input type="radio"> @Html.Label(Model.AnswerA)<br>
            <input type="radio"> @Html.Label(Model.AnswerB)<br>
            <input type="radio"> @Html.Label(Model.AnswerC)<br>
            <input type="radio"> @Html.Label(Model.AnswerD)<br>
            <input type="radio"> @Html.Label(Model.AnswerE)<p>
                <br />
                <button>Təsdiq</button>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
Service service = new Service();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = service.ListOfLastPosts().ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
 public ActionResult AcceptTest()
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            var model = service.ListOfTest().ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AcceptTest(Test test,string p_answer)
        {
            //if(service.CheckTest(test.Id,))
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Create a complex type model then use it in index.

Comment: But they are different.Is not it?

Comment: @PowerStar I am tired.Please help me with simple code.

Comment: Create the main model and add into other child models.